# How to create locking user feature after failed attempts in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and want to create a feature to lock the user after 5 log in attempts to the application from scratch without using DEVISE gem

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with these**

- create a field called **failed_attempts=0** and ***lock_flag=false***
- whenever user tries to login with invalid credentials increment
  **failed_attempts** counter
- once failed_attempts reaches limit lock user by setting **lock_flag** to true
- So whenever user tries to login first check his **lock_flag** if false
  then continue otherwise  throw error.

Note: If successful login then reset **failed_attempts** to zero